# PostgreSQL error codes are not returned in int?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have my java program connected to postgresql. I want to retrieve the error codes for sqlexception. I found the error code for postgresql  [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

But Java's `SQLException` contains only methods for error codes returned as int `getErrorCode()`

But the error codes in the link are not of the type int. Where can I get the int error codes for postgresql?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that getSQLState() is what you are looking for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState()